# How do I use a date collected from a user

Tags: workflow

[image]When I use "set workflow variable" to assign a variable the value of "collect2", which is the variable created by the "collect" command, i get "Coercion Failed: Unable to transform the input lookup data into the requested type."

Comment: show your workflow code, please.

Comment: I'm using sharepoint designer 2010, I don't have code that I can copy and paste. I added a screen shot to the original message

Comment: What is the variable type of collect2? What is the type of SMT run date variable?

Comment: collect2 is List Item ID, SMT run date is date/time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ListItemID cannot convert into a date, change the first line output to SMT run date variable, then you can delete the last line in the screenshot. So the code should look like this:

```
Collect Get run date from Master Scheduler from Steve Scott (Output to Variable: collect2)
then Log received date from master scheduler... to the workflow history list
Set Variable: SMT run date to (See Picture)
```

[image]

Comment: it doesn't let me select it. It will let me create a new variable but only of type List Item ID

Comment: Sorry, misspoke. The collect2 variable is the listitem of the task assigned to Steve Scott. See my edit. Instead of Due Date it should be the field that Steve Scott inputs to the date you are looking for.